# remove object using filter doesn't work using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's wrong with my code below?

```js
var arr = [{
  "key": 123,
  "player_data": {
    "id": 1

  }
}, {
  "key": 456,
  "player_data": {
    "id": 1

  }
}]

arr.filter(function(el) {
  return el.key != 123;
});

console.log(arr);
```

I expect the object with key 123 will be removed?

Comment: First find the index of the element you to remove and then use array.splice to remove the element.

Comment: should be `arr = arr.filter...`

Answer (score 0):

`arr.filter()` returns a new array and does not change the original. You are logging the original which has not been affected. Try..

```
var arr = [{
    "key": 123,
        "player_data": {
        "id": 1

    }
}, {
    "key": 456,
        "player_data": {
        "id": 1

    }
}]

var foo = arr.filter(function (el) {
    return el.key !== 123;
});

console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update

```
arr.filter(function (el) {
    return el.key != 123;
});
```

to

```
arr = arr.filter(function (el) {
    return el.key != 123;
});
```

**Note** : `filter` function does not change the existing array rather returns a new array.

For reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter